# Android - Pass Multiple List<AbstractType> to BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

I have an abstract class AbstractCard which I want to use as my List data to pass to my `BaseAdapter`. I don't want to pass a `List<AbstractCard>` though to the `BaseAdapter` but instead pass a `List<Object>` that extends AbstractCard.

For example, I have a class Card that extends AbstractCard. In my BaseAdapter I have:

```
private List<AbstractCard> abstractCards = new ArrayList<AbstractCard>();

public void setData(List<AbstractCard> abstractCards) {
    this.abstractCards = abstractCards;
}
```

Now, since Card extends AbstractCard, I would think that I could pass a `List<Card>` to setData() but it obviously gives me errors. How can I make it so I require a type based off of its parent class?

Comment: whats your error , please post your logcat values !!

Comment: There is no logcat values, it wont compile. If I try to pass a List<Card> to setData() eclipse says that my arguments are not applicable for the method.

Comment: thats because the type has changed , u are passing subclass instead of parent abstract class !! in java you can refer to subclass object from parent class reference but opposite doesn't hold here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with:

```
private List<? extends AbstractCard> abstractCards = new ArrayList<AbstractCard>();

public void setData(List<? extends AbstractCard> abstractCards) {
    this.abstractCards = abstractCards;
}
```

and then:

```
someClass.setData(new ArrayList<ConcreteCard>());
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate a `List` because is an interface (see [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). You have to use a concrete class that implements `List`. For example use a `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Card> list = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

Comment: well , i think he is doing that :- 
"private List<AbstractCard> abstractCards = new ArrayList<AbstractCard>();"  and that is pretty applicable !!